Is there a Perl module / a simple way to wrap methods of an object in a subroutine?
Title;
I have a Perl class, let's call it Foo, and I would like to conditionally and automatically (automatically as in: without changing the implementation of its methods) wrap some of its instances' methods (not the class' methods!) in a subroutine that, on one of the methods' invokation, will do some stuff before calling the target method itself.
Example:
package Foo;

sub new {
    my $self = bless({}, shift);

    my $wrap = shift;

    # I want to conditionally wrap **the blessed reference's**
    # methods here, based on a list of methods names, depending on
    # the value of $wrap; this is done so that the caller can decide
    # whether to wrap its own instance's methods or not, and so
    # that, if it decides to do so, a subroutine will run **before**
    # a method listed in the list of methods is run

    return $self;
}

sub method1 {
    return;
}

sub method2 {
    return;
}

# [...]

The wrapper should have access to the arguments passed by the caller to the target method (such as 'foo' and 'bar' in Foo -> method1('foo', 'bar'))
What I've tried:

Hook::LexWrap: it works fine, but it can only transparently wrap class methods (not what I want, as wrapping the class' methods defeats the purpose of wrapping only some specific instances' methods); it can wrap anonymous subroutines, however, in that case, it will return a reference to the wrapped subroutine, which defeats the purpose of automatically wrapping the methods;
Perinci::Sub::Wrapper: I didn't really try this, as it appears to also return a reference to the wrapped subroutine;
I looked at another module, which I can't recall the name of. That also suffered from one of these two problems.

I'll gladly accept a module suggestion as well as a simple idea on how to implement this myself (just the idea is fine, I should be able to implement it myself as long as I'm pointed in the right direction).

If you told us why you want to do this, maybe we could offer a different solution without the gymnastics.

@briandfoy The class is very generic, and used by many modules within a project; I need to track the usage of some methods when the class is instantiated in specific modules (I need to know when some methods are called by certain modules and using which values, to then run some statistics, so some sort of logging).

@briandfoy I know I could change some logic in the callers and track stuff there, and I'll resort to that if nothing better comes up, but that'd be quite the endeavour considering I'll have to do this for multiple modules and that, in the future, requirements will surely change, and that I'll have to do this again. So handling this during the class' instantiation would be much preferable. I hope this is enough information, I don't want to make this overly complex to parse.

Since there is no distinction between class and instance methods in perl, you can't modify the behavior of an instance without changing the class at the same time.
Possible options are changing the class definition to

include code in the instances (see answer by @ikegami)
include state in the instances to execute code conditionally
add a delegate to the instances (like a logger object) which might be a silent dummy

Another possibility is to rebless the object into a derived class (for only this one instance), that modifies the behavior. This has the advantage, that it works with any existing class/method without changing the original package.
The following example dynamically creates a subclass for the instance passed in, wraps the requested methods and reblesses the instance into that class. The class is removed when the object is destroyed.
While it would be possible to have this wrapper be part of the original class and take a constructor argument,it made more sense to me to have a seperate package for it so it can be applied to any class/method.
MyClass.pm
package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.032;
sub new{
    return bless {};
}

sub method1 {
   say 'MyClass::method1';
}

sub method2 {
   say 'MyClass::method2';
}
1;

InstanceWrapper.pm:
package InstanceWrapper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.032;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';
use Sub::Install;
use Symbol 'delete_package';
my $id = 0;

sub wrap{
    shift;
    my $instance = shift;
    my ($wrapped_methods,$coderef) = @_;
    my $wrapped_class = blessed($instance);
    my $classname = sprintf( '%s::%s::%d', $wrapped_class, 'Wrapped', $id++ );
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        @{ "${classname}::ISA" } = $wrapped_class;
    }
    for my $method (@$wrapped_methods){
        my $wrapped_meth = $wrapped_class->can($method);
        Sub::Install::install_sub({
            code => sub{
                say "calling coderef";
                $coderef->(@_);
                say "calling original $method";
                $wrapped_meth->(@_);
            },
            into => $classname,
            as   => $method,
        });
    }
    Sub::Install::install_sub({
         code => sub{
             say "removing package $classname";
             delete_package($classname);
         },
         into => $classname,
         as   => 'DESTROY',
    });
    bless $instance, $classname;
}
1;

test.pl:
use 5.032;
use warnings;
use strict;
use lib '.';
use MyClass;
use InstanceWrapper;
use Data::Dumper;
my $inst = MyClass->new();
my $inst2 = MyClass->new();
my $logger =  sub{say "wrapped call args:\n",Dumper \@_};
InstanceWrapper->wrap($inst, ['method1'],$logger);
$inst->method1('arg');  # wrapped
$inst2->method1('arg'); # not wrapped
InstanceWrapper->wrap($inst2,['method2'],$logger);
$inst->method2;   # not wrapped
undef $inst;      # DESTROY removes symbol table entry for $inst
$inst2->method2;  # wrapped
                  # $inst2 out of scope removes symbol table entry for $inst2

Output:
calling coderef
wrapped call args:
$VAR1 = [
          bless( {}, 'MyClass::Wrapped::0' ),
          'arg'
        ];

calling original method1
MyClass::method1
MyClass::method1
MyClass::method2
removing package MyClass::Wrapped::0
calling coderef
wrapped call args:
$VAR1 = [
          bless( {}, 'MyClass::Wrapped::1' )
        ];

calling original method2
MyClass::method2
removing package MyClass::Wrapped::1


Thank you, especially for putting in the effort of also providing an implementation. I kinda thought of this, I just hoped there was a simpler solution but hey, I'll leave this up for a bit, otherwise this seems viable. Thanks!

I wrote Wrap::Sub to do this kind of thing:
Package:
package Package;

use warnings;
use strict;

use Wrap::Sub;

sub new {
    my ($class, $wrap) = @_;

    my $self = bless { wrap => $wrap }, $class;

    my @to_wrap = qw (
        one
        three
    );

    if ($wrap) {
        my $wrapper = Wrap::Sub->new;

        for (@to_wrap) {
            my $sub = __PACKAGE__ . "::$_";

            $self->{wrapped}{$sub} = $wrapper->wrap(
                $sub,
                pre => sub {
                    my ($self, @params) = @_;
                    if ($self->{wrap}) {
                        print "$Wrap::Sub::name is wrapped!\n";
                        if (@params) {
                            print(join(', ', @params) . "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    return $self;
}

sub one {
    print "in sub one\n";
}

sub two {
    print "in sub two\n";
}

sub three {
    print "in sub three\n";
}

1;

Script:
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib '.';

use Package;

my $instance = Package->new(1);

$instance->one;
$instance->two;
$instance->three(1, 2 ,3);

Output:
Package::one is wrapped!
in sub one
in sub two
Package::three is wrapped!
1, 2, 3
in sub three


Sorry I couldn't get back at this before, but it seemed promising and I wanted to try it myself (I haven't had the chance yet), I went through your code and I can't see how this manages to wrap "instance methods", is it what it does? Or does it wrap class methods? I mean I see it passes the namespaced method names to wrap and that it stores the returned values in $self -> {wrapped_subs}, is this the black magic that somehow allows wrapping the "instance methods" instead of the class methods? I really hope it is... Thanks!

It wraps whatever methods you choose in the @to_wrap array. If you create an instance with the wrap parameter set to a false value, that instance won't have the methods wrapped.

Yes I understood that, but my concern is about whether this has "instance" method wrapped as opposed to "class methods" wrapped; let's put it like so: If I instantiated two objects of the same "wrappable" class, wrapping the first and not wrapping the second (my $o1 = Package -> new(1) and my $o2 = Package -> new()), would calling a method "wrapped" in the first instance (say one) using the second instance ($o2 -> one) also trigger the wrapper function?

No. Only the instance that was instantiated with the wrap param set to true would have the wrapped subs triggered

Amazing, thanks a lot, +1 for now but I'll accept this for sure once I've managed to test it. Thank you for providing this tool, I've looked at at least three modules doing "wrapping" of subs, this apparently is the only one that allows for this to happen!

I tried to test this: Instantiated $inst1=Package->new(1); then instantiated $inst2=Package->new(); Invoking methods on those two instances yields the same result (both instances running the wrapped code). Which is what I expect when you modify the subs in Package.

@clamp I forgot to add the code that checks the wrap status :) Try it now

This works if you only have one instance enabling the wrapper. However if you have more than one wrapped instance you get nested wrappers on all of them. Looks like it would be way easier to wrap unconditionally and use a simple flag in the instances...

Perl's object system doesn't have instance-specific methods. All methods come from the class, including class methods (Class->foo) and instance methods ($obj->foo).

Since you appear to have a fixed list of per-instance methods you want to override, you could use something like the following:
package Foo;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   
   my $self = bless( { }, $class );

   $self->{ method1 } = sub { ... };
   $self->{ method2 } = sub { ... };

   return $self;
}

sub method1 { $_[0]{ method1 }->( @_ ) }
sub method2 { $_[0]{ method2 }->( @_ ) }

1


Is the usage I want to make of this class that peculiar? It's not exactly my purpose, but what if, say, I wanted to automatically log some method calls using a logger class, but just on some specific instances? Would I be left with changing all methods to either log / not log based on some instance value? No way to quickly insert a wrapper around some of them? :| thanks anyways, +1 for now

@kos you can do the flag thing, or you can rebless the instances into a subclass that has the logging wrappers.

Re "Is the usage I want to make of this class that peculiar?", Well, you said you wanted instance-specific methods, and I said that Perl's object model doesn't have those. So obviously yes.

@hobbs Note that reblessing breaks inheritance

@ikegami if it's into a subclass of the original? How so?

@hobbs, When Foo is the subclass.
